# Fibonacci sequence in Python3.2

Tags: python, fibonacci, nameerror

I really need your help. I know this question has been asked countless times already but I still cant find the answer...

I need to programm a fibonacci sequence recursively in a bla-bla.py file, this is what I've got so far:

```
print("Unendlicher Fibonacci-Generator Rekursiv")
def fib(n):

  if n == 0:
        return 0
  elif n == 1:
        return 1
  else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

for n in fib(n):
  print (str(n))
```

But I always get a NameError "name 'n' is not defined" which is driving me crazy... I just cannot understand how one can "print" the value of a variable in Python! Please help!

I tried to use "in" to get rid of this NameError. I've programmed one Fibonacci Generator before and it worked perfectly fine exactly with that "for...in". I do understand i need some kind of iteration for it to work. So this is the version that works fine:

```
print("Unendlicher Fibonacci-Generator")
def fibonacci():
  a, b = 0, 1   #a=0, b=1
  while True:
    yield a
    a, b = b, a + b
f = fibonacci()

counter = 0
for x in f:
  print ("fib(" + str(counter) +") = " +str(x))
  counter +=1
  if (counter > 25): break
```

Can someone tell me what the correct code is for the recursive function?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to *pass in an integer* instead of `n`. There is no global `n` before your `for` loop starts.

Comment: I don't see what `for n in fib(n)` means.

Try for instance

`for n in range(10): print(fib(n))`

Comment: Note that your recursive function **does not produce a sequence** either. It produces a single result.

Comment: Your problem is not Fibonacci, it's Python. Learn the language. There are many *many* tutorials.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
print("Unendlicher Fibonacci-Generator Rekursiv")
def fib(n):

  if n == 0:
        return 0
  elif n == 1:
        return 1
  else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)


row=[fib(n) for n in range(1,25)]
print row
```

Comment: This solution with list comprehension prints nested lists. I don't think that was the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of things wrong with your code.

1) `fib(n)` - `n` is not defined. Instead, pass in a specific number like: `fib(5)`

2) `in` - You cannot do `in int`. Just print the result of the function call as follows:

```
print(fib(12))

[OUTPUT]
144
```

Here is a non-recursive approach to get a list of values:

```
def fib(n,):
    l = [0, 1]
    for i in range(n-2):
        l.append(l[-1]+l[-2])
    return l

>>> print fib(10)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Comment: @user3652491, A generator is different from a return function. In this case, you cannot use `in`. The two methods I have shown in my answer should be helpful (hopefully)

Comment: That worked, thank you very much! And sorry for probably such a simple question, I'm really new to IT :)

Comment: @user3652491, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks

Comment: Hope I did it right :)

Comment: @user3652491, Yes. Good luck with your coding...

Answer (score -1):

```
print("Unendlicher Fibonacci-Generator Rekursiv")
def fib(n):

  if n == 0:
        return 0
  elif n == 1:
        return 1
  else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)


print fib(12)

####### or a number which given by user
a=input("enter a number : ")
print("fibonacci(",a,") = ",fib(a))
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answers! But I get a syntax error after "print fib(12)". Actually the task is to make a fib. generator till 25

Comment: can you give me the error message ?

Comment: Either this is 2.x, in which case you shouldn't be using `input`, or 3.x, in which case `a` is a string.

Comment: vmadmin@vmLP1:~/Dokumente/modul122/M122_Scripts/Python$ python3.2 fib_rek.py
  File "fib_rek.py", line 9
    print fib(10)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Replace 
print("fibonacci(",a,") = ",fib(a))
by 
print("fibonacci(",a,") = ",fib(int(a)))

Comment: @angel please just use string formatting - `"fibonacci({0}) = {1}".format(a, fib(int(a)))`

Comment: i didn't know that i could do it in python :-D sorry

Comment: It does work, but it only shows the fib. number of a number i type in. What i need is a row of numbers from 0 to 25 with the corresponding fibs